# "You let me one for read" or "Let me read one for you"

Tags: grammar

There are some words and I have to rearrange these for making a sentence. those words are " me, let, you,  for, read, one". I arranged them like " you let me one for read" and the other sentence is " let me read one for you". I want to know that which sentence is correct?

Comment: Your version doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, “let me read one for you” is the correct sentence because it is the only grammatically correct and sensible sentence that can result from a combination of these words. It means to allow the speaker (“me”) read something for “you;” in this case, “I” am telling (in a non-forceful way) “you” that I will read something for you.

But I am curious to know your thought process behind your first example sentence. What do you think it means? Why do you think it’s a viable sentence?

Answer (score -1):

"Let me read one, for you."

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL! We expect answers to be detailed and explanatory. Please say more about why your suggestion works.

Comment: And why you think a comma is necessary.

Comment: I would disagree with the comma placement there.